# allow all favorites to show on one page

Tags: feature-request

Since the search within favorites feature is shelved for the moment, it would be helpful if I could see all my favorites on one page. For some users this will results in a metric ton of html, but for a typical user this is probably manageable.

Why? So I can search within the page text. For example: I know I favorited a question about left joins in LINQ. So I go to my favorites page, search for the word LINQ. Don't find it. Go to next page, repeat search, go to next page, repeat search, go to next page, repeat search. If all my favorites were on one page it'd be more useful for me to search in them by text.

Just need a button down by the pages of favorites that says "All".

Comment: Why don't you modify one of these Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries?  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=favorites